# How To Hide the "Check Out" from ECB Menu in 2007

Tags: list, ecb-menu

I've tried all the Blog techniques but must be missing something.  I need to hide the "Check Out" Edit Control Block Menu Item on a Form Library but I don't want to modify the Masterpage with a custom core.js file.  Can someone offer a jQuery solution?

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide 'Check out" ECB item, probably you don't want users to check-out the files. This setting can be turned off from library settings>Version Settings>Require Check Out=No.

If you want to hide it for specific users, remove their permissions to edit items.

Anyway,If you need to hide the ECB menu items using Jquery or core.js, Please check out :

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2011/10/29/hide-menu-ecb/

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a blog post about it long back, may be it can help you - http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-Hiding-Menu-Items-from-the-Edit-Control-Block.aspx